# If $\langle A,R \rangle $ is a well-ordering, then for all $x\in A, \langle A,R\rangle \ncong \langle \text{pred}(A,x,R),R\rangle .$

Tags: set-theory

The following is from Kenneth Kunen's book *Set Theory : An Introduction to Independent Proofs*

> Whenever $R$ and $S$ are relations, and $A,B$ are sets, we say $\langle A,R\rangle \cong \langle B,S\rangle$ iff there is a bijection $f: A\rightarrow B$ such that $\forall x, y\in A \left(x Ry \iff f(x)Sf(y)\right).$ $f$ is called an *isomorphism* from $\langle A, R\rangle$ to $\langle B, S\rangle.$
>
> We say $R$ *well-orders* $A,$ or $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a *well-ordering* iff $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a total ordering and every non-empty subset of $A$ has an $R$- least element.
>
> if $x\in A,$ let $\text{pred}(A,x,R) = \{y\in A:yRx\}$
>
> $6.1$ LEMMA. If $\langle A,R \rangle $ is a well-ordering, then for all $x\in A, \langle A,R\rangle \ncong \langle \text{pred}(A,x,R),R\rangle  .$
>
> PROOF.  If $f : A \rightarrow \text{pred}(A,x,R)$ were an isomorphism, derive a contradiction by considering the $R$-least element of $\{y\in A :f(y)\ne y\}.$

I am just confused about why would we need to define such a set to arrive at a contradiction? What would go wrong if I choose to argue the following way instead?

Suppose there is some $x_0\in A$ such that $f : A \rightarrow \text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ is an isomorphism. This implies that $A = \text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ since $f$ is a bijection. But $x_0\notin \text{pred}(A,x_0,R)$ because $R$ is irreflexive. This implies $x_0 \notin A$

Comment: Notice that the analogous result for linear orderings fails.  What goes wrong with your proof in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isomorphism doesn't imply equality.

For instance, as well-orders, $(\mathbb{N},\leq) \cong (\mathbb{N}\setminus \{4\}, \leq)$ but $\mathbb{N} \neq \mathbb{N}\setminus \{4\}$.